# Predicting features with TensorFlow JS using strings as input

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to predict some personal features from job profiles using TensorFlow JS.

My dataset is something like this (actually 20 entries):

```
Title, Proactivity, Effort, Diligence, Flexibility, Resilience
"Web designer",0.8,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.2
"Web developer",0.5,0.9,0.5,0.8,0.3
...
```

The input is `title`, and the output variables are the rest (`Proactivity`, `Effort`, `Diligence`, `Flexibility`, `Resilience`).

So I want to predict the features depending on the `title`, taking into account for example if the title does not exist then it can be approached by similarity of terms and that's why I use this approach in TensorFlowJS:

1. encode the title set using the module `@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder` to use them in the model input, so that the training input has a shape `[N,512]`, where `N` is the lenght of train dataset.
2. when predicting, I convert the string of a given job title to a tensor again with `@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder` and that is the value I use to predict (shape `[1,512]`)

This is the code:

```js
    
    const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
    const tf_use = require("@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder");

    // Input titles are encoded with @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder into a tensor
    let jobtitles = ["Web designer","Web developer"]

    const shape = [job_titles.length, 512]
    const dtype = "float32"
    let model_use = await tf_use.load()
    let embeddings = await model_use.embed(job_titles)
    let st = await embeddings.data()

    const input_tensor = tf.tensor(st, shape, dtype)      
    //Output 
    const output_tensor = tf.tensor2d([[0.8,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.8],[0.5,0.9,0.5,0.8,0.3]])

    // Build the model
    const model = tf.sequential()

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({
        inputShape: [512],
        activation: "sigmoid",
        units: 64
    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ activation: "softmax", units: 5 }))

    model.compile({
        loss: "meanSquaredError",
        optimizer: "sgd",
    });

    // Fit the model
    await model.fit(
        input_tensor,
        output_tensor, {
        epochs: 100,
        callbacks: {
            onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
                console.log(epoch + ':' + logs.loss);
            }
        }
    }).then(async () => {
        
        // Encode a Job title to predict the features
        let m_use = await tf_use.load()
        let embeddings = await m_use.embed(["Web manager"])
        let st = await embeddings.data()
        
        const shape = [1, 512]
        const dtype = "float32"

        let input_value = tf.tensor(st, shape, dtype)    
        const prediction = model.predict(input_value);

        console.log(prediction.print())
        
      });
```

The prediction output is something like
`[[0.1170303, 0.2825571, 0.4244316, 0.1430101, 0.0329709],]`

My questions are as follows:

- 1.- Would it be correct to use the @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder to convert the input strings to a tensor and that the model takes into account the similarity in the titles?
- 2.- Does it make sense to use @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder to convert the string to predict?
- 3.- As for that prediction result, I find it strange that it does not look much like the already existing values of characteristics.
- 4.- What approach do you recommend me to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!